# Adding a new row to a ListView makes the ones above it disappear

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I've got a ListView that is populated using a custom BaseAdapter (MyBaseAdapter) :

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    private View renderer;

    List<MyItemModel> items;

    public MyBaseAdapter(View renderer) {
        this.renderer = renderer;
    }

    public void setModel(List<MyItemModel> items)
    {

        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {

        return items != null ? items.size() : 0;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {

        return items != null ? items.get(position) : null;
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {

        return items != null ? items.get(position).id : -1;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = renderer;
        }
        MyItemModel item = items.get(position);
        // replace those R.ids by the ones inside your custom list_item layout.
        TextView timeText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
        timeText.setText(item.time);

        ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(item.listener);

        ImageView coinImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.coinImage);
        coinImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_refresh);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

It's populated using these items

```
public class MyItemModel
{

String time;
long id;

OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("app", "whatever");
    }
};

}
```

And I add items to it from my Main class using code like this:

```
private void setUpList()
{

    myListModel = new ArrayList<MyItemModel>();

    MyItemModel item = new MyItemModel();
    item.time = "12:00";
    item.id = 0;
    myListModel.add(item);

   //if I add a few more items here, it still only shows the bottom one

    LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
                      //alarm_list_item is a table row 
    View view = li.inflate(R.layout.alarm_list_item, null);

    adapter = new MyBaseAdapter(view);
    adapter.setModel(myListModel);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

}
```

And that works fine until I add another item to the list when this happens (note the row above it is blank. If I add more than one rows, all rows apart from the last one are blank like this.)

Any ideas what's going on?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the background of your problem, but member *renderer* in your Adapter seam a little strange. It make all the item view in the *listView* the first itemView created.

I think you can try modify your *getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)* method as below:

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    //private View renderer;
    private Context mContext;


    List<MyItemModel> items;

    public MyBaseAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void setModel(List<MyItemModel> items)
    {

        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {

        return items != null ? items.size() : 0;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {

        return items != null ? items.get(position) : null;
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {

        return items != null ? items.get(position).id : -1;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.alarm_list_item, null);
        }
        MyItemModel item = items.get(position);
        // replace those R.ids by the ones inside your custom list_item layout.
        TextView timeText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
        timeText.setText(item.time);

        ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(item.listener);

        ImageView coinImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.coinImage);
        coinImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_refresh);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

and in your *setUpList()*, pass your host activity as parameter when constructing your adapter:

```
private void setUpList(){

    MyItemModel item = new MyItemModel();
    item.time = "12:00";
    item.id = 0;
    myListModel.add(item);

    LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
                  //alarm_list_item is a table row 
    View view = li.inflate(R.layout.alarm_list_item, null);

    //adapter = new MyBaseAdapter(view);
    adapter = new MyBaseAdapter(Activity.this);
   adapter.setModel(myListModel);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

}
```

May it helps

Comment: Thanks so much! I think I need to learn a bit more about adapters and renderers and the like!

Answer (score 5):

What on earth are you doing? /trying to do?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = renderer;
    }
    //...//
}
```

Only your last item will get a view to render!

Try to add 100 items (to enable scrolling) and scroll! you will see how awesome it is.

---

*Solution:*
You will have to inflate a new View each time your convertView is null. Returning the same view will show the last position for which `getView` is called.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, but Song's answer ultimately helped me get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to move `myListModel = new ArrayList<MyItemModel>();` outside the `setUpList()` method, with the way you have it, you are creating a new array everytime you call `setUpList()` so you only have one item in the array the whole time, if you move the array declaration outside the method, the items will be added to the array correctly

```
myListModel = new ArrayList<MyItemModel>();

private void setUpList(){

    MyItemModel item = new MyItemModel();
    item.time = "12:00";
    item.id = 0;
    myListModel.add(item);

    LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
                  //alarm_list_item is a table row 
    View view = li.inflate(R.layout.alarm_list_item, null);

    adapter = new MyBaseAdapter(view);
    adapter.setModel(myListModel);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip but I don't think this is causing the problem. Even if I duplicate the line `myListModel.add(item);` a few times, it still causes the problem.